# Discord.js - Why is the messageReactionAdd event completely blocked?

Tags: discord.js

I've been trying to create a Discord bot. A lot of interactions are done through reactions, and I've been aware of the fact that only cached messages triggered the messageReactionAdd event. So I picked the following piece of code that is supposed to emit the packets corresponding to reactions added to "old" (**not cached**) messages. But it seems to completely block any packets concerning reactions adding because now none is emitted. Is there something that I've been doing wrong ?
Thanks.

My "raw.js" file :

```
module.exports = {
    run: (client, packet) => {

        // We don't want this to run on unrelated packets
        if (!['MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD', 'MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE'].includes(packet.t)) return;
        // Grab the channel to check the message from
        const channel = client.guilds.cache.get(packet.d.guild_id).channels.cache.get(packet.d.channel_id);

        const messageID = packet.d.message_id;
        // There's no need to emit if the message is cached, because the event will fire anyway for that
        if (channel.messages.has(messageID)) return;

        // Since we have confirmed the message is not cached, let's fetch it
        channel.messages.fetch(messageID).then(message => {
            // Emojis can have identifiers of name:id format, so we have to account for that case as well
            const emoji = packet.d.emoji.id ? `${packet.d.emoji.name}:${packet.d.emoji.id}` : packet.d.emoji.name;
            // This gives us the reaction we need to emit the event properly, in top of the message object
            const reaction = message.reactions.get(emoji);
            // Adds the currently reacting user to the reaction's users collection.
            if (reaction) reaction.users.set(packet.d.user_id, client.users.get(packet.d.user_id));
            // Check which type of event it is before emitting
            if (packet.t === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD') {
                client.emit('messageReactionAdd', reaction, client.users.get(packet.d.user_id));
            }
            if (packet.t === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE') {
                client.emit('messageReactionRemove', reaction, client.users.get(packet.d.user_id));
            }
        });
    }
};
```

My "event fetcher" :

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readdir('./events/', (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach((file) => {
        const eventFunction = require(`./events/${file}`);
        if (eventFunction.disabled) return;

        const event = eventFunction.event || file.split('.')[0];
        const emitter = (typeof eventFunction.emitter === 'string' ? client[eventFunction.emitter] : eventFunction.emitter) || client;
        const { once } = eventFunction;

        try {
            emitter[once ? 'once' : 'on'](event, (...args) => eventFunction.run(client, ...args));
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.stack);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [discord.js discord server's](https://discord.gg/bRCvFy9) `#faq` channel:

> Bug:
>
> • `'messageReactionAdd'` does not fire despite proper partials enabled
>
> PR: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/4969 (merged, waiting for release)
>
> Temporary fix is to ensure the addition of `GUILD_MEMBER` partial in the client definition
>
> ```js
> new Discord.Client({
>  partials: ['USER', 'GUILD_MEMBER', 'CHANNEL', 'MESSAGE', 'REACTION'],
> });
> ```